# ON_EN_CHANGE event/handler not being called for RichEditControl

Tags: c++, .net, winapi, mfc

I have a richedit control that is not calling its `ON_EN_CHANGE` event. I also have an `ON_EN_KILLFOCUS` event that is being used, and it works perfectly fine. The `ON_EN_CHANGE` event does not even enter is block, but its mapping is declared. Does anyone have any idea what could possibly be going wrong?

If it helps any, I also have spin control buddied with (regular, not RICH) edit controls, and those edit controls `ON_EN_CHANGE` events work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`EM_SETEVENTMASK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774238(v=vs.85).aspx) message to specify which events you want a rich edit control to notify you about (in MFC, this is the [`CRichEditCtrl::SetEventMask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0wxk560.aspx) method).

In this particular case, you would want `ENM_CHANGE` events.

Comment: exactly what I needed. thank you so much :) completely forgot about masks